# How to connect to the database in ddev?

Tags: typo3, ddev

I installed successfully ddev for TYPO3 and now want to connect to the mariadb database. But what are the credentials? If I ssh into the container and want to connect I got a password prompt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Access via external tools is described in [Using Developer Tools with ddev](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/developer-tools/).

Specifically you need to execute the following command to get the necessary credentials:

```
ddev describe
```

Comment: When you ssh into the web container, the credentials are at host 'db', so db:db@db/db.  So in the web container you could use `mysql -udb -pdb -hdb --database=db` and it would work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Both answers work. I updated this morning ddev to the recent version 0.18.0, after executing ddev config again, the AdditionalConfiguration.php with the database credentials was created.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading my ddev and deleting all the containers, everything stayed the same except my new port number incremented up by one.

```
mariadb
Host: localhost:portNumberIncrementedByOne
User/Pass: 'db/db'
```